# GlobalScope.launch is "delicate" - how to deal with?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I'm in the process of updating my Kotlin Android app to use Coroutines 1.5.2 (previously used 1.4.3).

In 1.5.2, any uses of `GlobalScope.launch` are now flagged with an inspection as "delicate":

https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/05/kotlin-coroutines-1-5-0-released/#globalscope

Let's say I know what I'm doing (in some cases I need a scope that won't go away with the containing activity / fragment).

How do I mark these uses so they don't get flagged? The following options are suggested, but none seem good.

Option 1 - Add `@DecliateCoroutinesApi` to the method. This makes the method also "delicate" and any call to *that* now get the inspection, so that achieves nothing.

Option 2 - Add `@DecliateCoroutinesApi` to the class. Seems like overkill.

Option 3 - Add `@OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)` to the method. Almost good, but requires a special compiler switch `-Xopt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn`. Kind of messy.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Option #4: Create your own `CoroutineScope` that has the lifetime that you want, and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *really* know what you're doing, option 3 should be the way to go. `@OptIn` is indeed experimental but that compiler flag is a small price to pay to use experimental features via `@OptIn` in general. You could also not use the compiler flag, and keep the warning about the `@OptIn` annotation itself, but that's even messier IMO.

That said, you should really think twice about using `GlobalScope`. Most of the time you can instead create a scope that you control yourself (with a dispatcher and maybe a `Job`/`SupervisorJob` as well, so you can cancel coroutines when appropriate).

Comment: Yeah I was also thinking about creating MyGlobalScope with a Job inside. Don't even need to cancel, this is for short-lived async tasks like saving data when a Fragment / Activity is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

You can even delete the GlobalScope, to keep just the async call (CoroutineScope.async).